# Does it exist a method to purge the DOM subtree that was removed from document (at least to stop images from this subtree from being loaded)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I've discovered that `document.removeChild()` does not actually destroy the DOM subtree, but only unlinks it from the document.

For me this means that images inside the unlinked subtree continue to load and consume memory for some time after subtree removal.

Of course, I can set the images' `src` attributes to empty string or `null` and hope this will stop them from being loaded, saving the traffic. Sorry, I didn't test this solution across many browsers yet.

But, I'm wondering if there is a more simple way to do this (force subtree purge?).

Here's the test code:

```
var url = 'http://habrahabr.ru/images/bg-multilogo.png?nocache=' + Date.now(),
    cleanTheSrc  = !true, /* todo: change and play */
    jQueryRemove = !true, /* todo: change and play */
    cleanTheLink = !true; /* todo: change and play */

var img = document.createElement('img');
console.log('img created');

img.onload  = function(){console.log('img loaded');};
img.onerror = function(){console.log('img aborted');};
img.src = url;

document.body.appendChild(img);
console.log('img added to DOM (synchronously)');

if (jQueryRemove) {
    $(img).remove();
    console.log('img removed from DOM using jQuery (synchronously)');
} else {
    document.body.removeChild(img);
    console.log('img removed from DOM natively (synchronously)');
}

if (cleanTheSrc) {
    img.src = '';
}

if (cleanTheLink) { // GC does not help actually, leave these lines here for fun
    img = null;
}
```

This shows us that the image continues to live "under the hood" after you remove it from DOM (or remove it's parent node).

My question is:

1. Is my solution to stop the image loading good enough for IE8+ and other popular browsers?
2. Is there any better way?

---

UPDATE:

For curious: we can add and remove element from DOM asynchronously, use other JS libraries and play with cache, for me this did not bring any solution.

I've added a few lines to try `jQuery.remove()`. Personally I get the same result in jQuery 1.6+.

Comment: As you tagged jquery I assume you have jQuery being loaded in your page. In that case, just use the [$.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function

Comment: @giorgio: I have tried to rewrite this example in jQuery, and I get the same result. `jQuery.remove()` seems to do the same thing as native `removeChild()`. Finally, I've decided to place native code and leave jQuery internals and realisations out of discussion. If `remove()` works in you case, please post the code.

Comment: It is actually impossible, well `window.stop` but that's not exactly ideal. Removing the src attribute has no effect as some people mistakenly believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and removing the element or it's container from DOM has no effect on image loading. So, it looks to be the wrong way. To prove it, let's run example above without DOM manipulation lines.

```
var url = 'http://habrahabr.ru/images/bg-multilogo.png?nocache=' + Date.now(),
img = document.createElement('img');
console.log('img created');

img.onload  = function(){console.log('img loaded');};
img.src = url;  // loads the image, no matter it's detached from DOM
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Something like

```
container.remove().find('img').attr('src', '');
```

is fast and simple enough.